# How to change axixY automatically in Chart?

Tags: c#

When I ran this code it gives me `myrate = 92,31` so it must between 100 and 80 like `100>92,31>80` but the problem is when my chart5 seems it seems like the picture.
[image]

```
while (dr.Read())
 {
  isdataexist = 1;
  string year = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
  string myrate = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
    if (year != "" || myrate != "")
       {
        this.chart5.Series["RATE"].Points.AddXY(year, myrate);
       }
   }
```

so how can I fix this problem.I need to see the "Y" Axix like `100 80 60 40 20`

I try to fix this problem with this code.But I don't know how.

```
chart5.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "???";
```

Comment: Step 1: Do not add values as strings! Then report back! Also: `92,31` sounds like you are using a european formatting; but for the machine and the chart this is `9231`..

Comment: so how can I fix it?

Comment: Start by deleting the `ToString()` from the code and making `myrate` a number.

Comment: taw it fix my problem thank youuu!!!